# Framezoom artifact when image is centered

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, zooming

When using the `framezoom` command, while centering the image;\

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Warsaw}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{center}

\framezoom<2><3>[border](3.5cm, 1.5cm)(1cm, 1cm)

\pgfimage[height=5cm]{example-image}

\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The image will be centered and the border will be positioned as if the center is 0.
But the zoom actually zooms on the part of the picture as if 0 is at the left of your slide.

So in short the border and zoom no longer match.
My question is: Can i use framezoom with a border while centering my image

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please always add a full, compilable but [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, not just code snippets. This way people can directly compile the code and test their solutions. I would also recommend to replace your image name with `example-image` so it can be easily compiled by other people who have the [`mwe`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) bundle installed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be a bug of `beamer` IMHO. The `\framezoom` might use some form of anchor which is affected by the centering.

One way to solve this is the place the `\framezoom` *outside* of the `center` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\framezoom<2><3>[border](3.5cm, 1.5cm)(1cm, 1cm)
\begin{center}
\pgfimage[height=5cm]{example-image}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that you can center images very easily using my `adjustbox` package if you use the `export` option and `\includegraphics`. `\pgfimage` is using `\includegraphics` for PDF output anyway AFAIK.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\framezoom<2><3>[border](3.5cm, 1.5cm)(1cm, 1cm)
\includegraphics[height=5cm,center]{example-image}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: perfect that fixed it, should have thought of that myself. Thanks alot

Answer (score 7):

[Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55293/3323) already gave good workarounds for this problem, so I want to fill in some information on why this happens:

The relevant code for `\framezoom` can be found in [`beamerbaseframesize.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaseframesize.sty), ll. 39-135:

```
\def\beamer@framezoom<#1><#2>[#3](#4,#5)(#6,#7){%
  % [...]
  \only<#1>{%
    {\hypersetup{pdfhighlight={/P},pdfborder={0 0 \beamer@zoomborderwidth}}%
    \global\setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{\hyperlink{\beamer@labelzoomed}{\vbox to #7{\hbox
          to#6{\hfil}\vfil}}}}%
    \ht\@tempboxa=0pt%
    \wd\@tempboxa=0pt%
    \dp\@tempboxa=0pt%
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{\moveright#4\hbox{\lower#5\vbox{\box\@tempboxa}}}%
    \ht\@tempboxa=0pt%
    \wd\@tempboxa=0pt%
    \dp\@tempboxa=0pt%
    \global\setbox\beamer@zoombox=\vbox to0pt{\unvbox\beamer@zoombox\box\@tempboxa}%
  }%
  % [...]
}
```

The above code snippet produces the clickable zoom frame and stores it in the box `\beamer@zoombox`, which is later inserted at the beginning of the frame (in [`beamerbaseframe.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/beamerbaseframe.sty), l. 144). So generally it shouldn't be a problem to use `\framezoom` anywhere in your frame, as the reference point is always the beginning of the frame text.

However, in your example, this is apparently not true. The reason is that you use `\framezoom` in a `center` environment, which changes the paragraph margins using `\leftskip`  and `\rightskip`. This messes up with the line

```
\global\setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{\hyperlink{\beamer@labelzoomed}{\vbox to #7{\hbox
      to#6{\hfil}\vfil}}}}%
```

in the above code: As the margin changes are in effect, `\hyperlink` is centered inside the `\vbox`, with the consequence of a wrong placement of the zoom frame. To overcome this, you have to enclose the link in another `\hbox`, like this:

```
\global\setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{\hbox{\hyperlink{\beamer@labelzoomed}{\vbox to #7{\hbox
      to#6{\hfil}\vfil}}}}}%
```

This can be done using `\patchcmd` from the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
  \patchcmd{\beamer@framezoom}{\hyperlink{\beamer@labelzoomed}{\vbox to #7{\hbox to#6{\hfil}\vfil}}}{\hbox{\hyperlink{\beamer@labelzoomed}{\vbox to #7{\hbox to#6{\hfil}\vfil}}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
  \framezoom<2><3>[border](3.5cm, 1.5cm)(1cm, 1cm)
  \pgfimage[height=5cm]{example-image}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, there may still be exotic paragraph parameters where this workaround will  also fail. So maybe it's best to stick to the advice given in the [`beamer` manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsection.11.3):

> This command [i.e. `\framezoom`] should be given somewhere at the beginning of a frame.

Comment: +1 It's always nice to look up the reason of these issues. I didn't had time to do it myself.